# What do I do if I can't figure out why OP wrote the wrong code they wrote?

Tags: discussion

OK, that probably sounds weird, so let me explain.  Wrong code is good.  It helps us understand the mistake or misunderstanding OP is making.  But sometimes, I can't figure out how OP thought the code would work in the first place.  Sometimes I get the sense that they are just throwing random code together and hoping it "just magically works," but maybe (being charitable) their mind works differently from mine.  Maybe they have some really weird understanding of programming in general or this language in particular and I'm just not smart enough to figure out what that understanding is.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055854/iterating-through-strings-inside-a-list), OP's code is wrong, but that's fine.  What's not fine is that I can't figure out what mistake or combination of mistakes would lead OP to believe their code would work in the first place (to be clear, I view this as a failing on *my* part rather than OP's).  The only way to answer these questions is to provide code that does what OP wants, which turns us back into the code writing service that we supposedly aren't.  I want to help questioners *understand* their questions, not just write their code for them.  Usually the answers are mostly just "Here's some code that does what you want" (kudos to the accepted answer for breaking down the correct code point-by-point, but you don't see that a lot in my experience, and I *still* can't figure out how this OP thought their wrong code would work).

What should I do with these questions?  I don't want to downvote them; they are typically rather well-written ("I'm trying to do X, but I get Y, here's my code, how do I make it do X instead?" -- hits all the essential points).  I just can't figure out where the OP is coming from.

Comment: Be patient. Talk to them through comments and try to get them to understand the question and the situation (which will in turn help you). If they can do that, you're off to a great start!

Comment: Nothing says you have to do anything.  If you don't understand and you think it is your own failure (not the OP's), then move on.  There will be another question to answer

Comment: While nobody should reasonably expect anyone to write their whole program for them, writing a single function or small class for them ought to be just fine.  Such answers have a much greater likelihood of being useful to others, compared to the usual "why doesn't my code work" questions, which tend to be too specific to the asker.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I disagree. If an answer to a question is simply a snippet of code which adheres to the posters specific business rules, then it's really of no use to the rest of the community. The kind of askers OP is talking about will come back in hours for the solution to their *next* problem. It ends up with SO being a code-writing service, but only in bite-sized pieces. There's a difference between writing code which is generic (which the example most definitely is not, or at the very least it's not searchable) and writing tailored code.

Comment: @Rob I am going to guess RobertHavey was being overly general.  But "how do I do this small thing" and get a short snippet is certainly more valuable than "what's wrong with my code".  More often than not, the "what's wrong with my code" will have virtually no long term value, but the "how do I do this small thing" is Googlable and potentially useful.  But overly specific "how do I" questions usually have more general canonical duplicates and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"I want to do X, here is some code that does Y"* is the new *"gimme teh codez"*.

I see this pattern more and more. OP is looking for a piece of code that does some specific task, but they don't know how the principle is called, cannot figure out how to write it themselves and they cannot find something that does it.

So they want to post a question on SO, but they know they can't just post *"I need some code that does X"*. So they include some marginally relevant code that in no way seems to even touch what they actually want to do.

Then some people start arguing in comments, casting confused down- and closevotes and in the meantime some sub 10K or super 100K user posts some code that lets OP continue.

Face it; most *"How to do X"* questions have simply already been asked, but nobody cares to make them more generally applicable and close new questions as duplicates of them. They rather repeat the code present in those questions, without including all the information present in these "canonical" questions and answers, and for what? To not have to discuss with OP why it *is* a duplicate?

[Something something fish, fire](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/387711-build-a-man-a-fire-and-he-ll-be-warm-for). As usual.

More often than not, askers who do this are actually asking a duplicate question, but they are confusing people who actually want to help them getting their code to work. They are not interested in getting that code to work, they want to get their problem solved, so any effort spent trying to understand what the code is supposed to do is usually wasted effort.

Problems causing this behavior:

- If you don't know what you're looking for is called, it is impossible to find it.
- If you do know it, because of the sheer volume, it has become impossible again to find what you're looking for. I'm an quite avid Googler and pretty damn well know my way around it, but questions that I *know* exist can sometimes not be found, because there are so many phrased like it.
- Answerers don't like searching for duplicates if typing an answer is faster.
- Askers asking *"I want to do X"* must accept that a duplicate explaining how to do X may not be directly copy-pasteable into their project and may require some more reading as opposed to an answer tailored to them, repeating (and omitting) information from any duplicate.

So, what should we do?

- Search before answering.
- Improve canonical questions so they are more readable and apply to the more generic cases.
- Pressure OP into providing relevant source and/or links to Q&As they found but could not figure out.
- Close as duplicate more freely, or if not certain at least post comments like *"Doesn't this question do what you want?"*.